# Import text file to HBase using importtsv

Tags: hadoop, import, hbase

## Problem:

I am trying to import data to an HBase database from a textfile using [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv.example) example from documentation.

## Configuration

HBase version:  `hbase-0.94.4`.

My installation is `Standalone` (Not Distributed or Pseudo-Distributed).

## Reproduce error

Initially it creates the StoreFiles on HDFS, and an empty table with the name `datatsv`, using:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath` ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop \
jar /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.4.jar importtsv \
-Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2 \
-Dimporttsv.bulk.output=/user/vm1/outputfile  datatsv /user/vm1/myfile.txt
```

Then, the CompleteBulkLoad methods loads data from StoreFile to table:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles \
/user/vm1/outputfile datatsv
```

The following command has the same output with the above one:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath` ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop \
jar /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.4.jar completebulkload \
/user/vm1/outputfile datatsv
```

The error message, by either commands, is:

```
ERROR mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Unexpected execution exception during splitting
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value of the hbase.metrics.showTableName conf option has not been specified in SchemaMetrics
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplitPhase(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:704)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value of the hbase.metrics.showTableName conf option has not been specified in SchemaMetrics
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaMetrics.getEffectiveTableName(SchemaMetrics.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaMetrics.getInstance(SchemaMetrics.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaConfigured.getSchemaMetrics(SchemaConfigured.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.close(HFileReaderV2.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.close(HFileReaderV2.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplit(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:321)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value of the hbase.metrics.showTableName conf option has not been specified in SchemaMetrics
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplitPhase(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:704)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value of the hbase.metrics.showTableName conf option has not been specified in SchemaMetrics
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaMetrics.getEffectiveTableName(SchemaMetrics.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaMetrics.getInstance(SchemaMetrics.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.metrics.SchemaConfigured.getSchemaMetrics(SchemaConfigured.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.close(HFileReaderV2.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.close(HFileReaderV2.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplit(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles$2.call(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:321)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

## Question

Am I missing anything?

Searched the mailing lists, asked on free node, and haven't found an answer. Also tried setting the setting a property of hbase (and restarting it) using:
`hbase.metrics.showTableName` to `false`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool I asked about in question is no longer working.
So, I've written some Java code, using the HBase API to do the bulk load using MapReduce.

Github link: [HBase Bulk Load](https://github.com/Paschalis/HBase-Bulk-Load-Example)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem a while back when I was trying to bulk load data using the Java API. I opened a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883023/hbase-bulk-load-exeception/13912831#13912831). I had to specify this line in my client application and that solved the issue: `SchemaMetrics.configureGlobally(conf)`. Now, there you don't use the Java API, all this line does is setting a property in the .xml configuration so you should be able to set it by hand. I would try this one: `hbase.metrics.showTableName`, which should already be `true` by default, but I would try to set it to `true` explicitly. At the moment I'm working on HBase 0.90 (the one that comes with Hortonworks HDP 1.1) and I don't even have to use `SchemaMetrics.configureGlobally(conf)` anymore. Maybe it's a bug (or just a new approach) in HBase 0.94?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried with false, as said in my post, and with true, but none of them worked! (i restarted hbase on each try). You used java to produce HFiles? Or for the import? Or both? Thanks again!

Comment: I used Java to do both. I wrote a MapReduce job that that used the `HFileOutputFormat` as outputformat and then used the `LoadIncrementalFiles` class to load these into my HBase table. I'll have another look at my configuration to see if I can find some more information.